# How to plot the line that separates 2 classes,using output of perceptron MATLAB

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, plot, perceptron

after running the [perceptron code in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882367/implementing-and-ploting-a-perceptron-in-matlab) I get the following weights:

```
result=
    2.5799
    2.8557
    4.4244
   -4.3156
    1.6835
   -4.0208
   26.5955
  -12.5730
   11.5000
```

If i started with these weights :

```
w = [ 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1]';
```

How do I plot the line that separates the 2 classes.
Is necessary to solve a linear system, but how?

```
Line = [result,w] 

% solve the linear system, am I correct doing this?
rref(Line')
```

- Is it correct the way to calculate the values, that will be use to plot?
- How to plot the line??
  any example???

Comment: Are you asking how to *calculate* the line (i.e. all its coefficients), or how to *plot* it once you know it.?

Comment: Both of them.
How to calculate it, well I tried using rref(Line') once I have the weights, but want to know if this aproach is the best, in the other hand to plot it, I know is using plot(... but what)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Yaux = sign(w'*X);  % w is the result of calling perceptron
scatter(X(1,:),X(2,:),100,Yaux);
hold on;
plot([0 w(1)], [0 w(2)]); 
hold off;
```

seems to work for 2 dimension

Comment: Could you explain in more detail for those that doesnt work with matlab? How did you get points for your separation line?