# creating a train perceptron in MATLAB for gender clasiffication

Tags: matlab, gradient, perceptron

I am coding a perceptron to learn to categorize gender in pictures of faces. I am very very new to MATLAB, so I need a lot of help. I have a few questions:

1. I am trying to code for a function:

   ```
   function [y] = testset(x,w)  
   %y = sign(sigma(x*w-threshold))
   ```

   where y is the predicted results, x is the training/testing set put in as a very large matrix, and w is weight on the equation. The part after the `%` is what I am trying to write, but I do not know how to write this in MATLAB code. Any ideas out there?
2. I am trying to code a second function:

   ```
   function [err] = testerror(x,w,y)  
   %err = sigma(max(0,-w*x*y))
   ```

   w, x, and y have the same values as stated above, and err is my function of error, which I am trying to minimize through the steps of the perceptron.
3. I am trying to create a step in my perceptron to lower the percent of error by using gradient descent on my original equation. Does anyone know how I can increment w using gradient descent in order to minimize the error function using an if then statement?

I can put up the code I have up till now if that would help you answer these questions.

Thank you!

edit--------------------------

OK, so I am still working on the code for this, and would like to put it up when I have something more complete. My biggest question right now is:

I have the following function:

```
function [y] = testset(x,w)  
y = sign(sum(x*w-threshold))
```

Now I know that I am supposed to put a threshold in, but cannot figure out what I am supposed to put in as the threshold! any ideas out there?

edit----------------------------
this is what I have so far. Changes still need to be made to it, but I would appreciate input, especially regarding structure, and advice for making the changes that need to be made!

```
function [y] = Perceptron_Aviva(X,w)
y = sign(sum(X*w-1));
end

function [err] = testerror(X,w,y)
    err = sum(max(0,-w*X*y));
end

%function [w] = perceptron(X,Y,w_init)
%w = w_init;
%end

%------------------------------

% input samples
X = X_train;

% output class [-1,+1];
Y = y_train;

% init weigth vector
w_init = zeros(size(X,1));
w = w_init;


%---------------------------------------------
loopcounter = 0

while abs(err) > 0.1 && loopcounter < 100

    for j=1:size(X,1)

        approx_y(j) = Perceptron_Aviva(X(j),w(j))

        err = testerror(X(j),w(j),approx_y(j))

        if err > 0 %wrong (structure is correct, test is wrong)
            w(j) = w(j) - 0.1 %wrong
        elseif err < 0 %wrong
            w(j) = w(j) + 0.1 %wrong
        end

       % -----------
       % if sign(w'*X(:,j)) ~= Y(j) %wrong decision?
       %      w = w + X(:,j) * Y(j);   %then add (or subtract) this point to w
    end
```

Comment: The Matlab documentation itself if fairly thorough and gives background material,small examples, and references.  Pull some papers specific to your field and see what methodologies they used.

Comment: What have you tried and what isn't working? Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Can you put all the code you have.

Comment: this is everything I have (there is code that for some reason did not come out highlighted above the highlighted section). The last part of the code is code that I was thinking about putting in from what you wrote.

Comment: I see that you have defined your data as `% input samples
X = X_train;
Y = y_train;` , I guess that loads the data... but you will need to **separate** the data in  2 classes aka, `-1` class `male`,  `1` class `female`, in the example I posted, it splits in 2 classes like:`X1=[rand(1,100);rand(1,100);ones(1,100)];   % class '+1'
X2=[rand(1,100);1+rand(1,100);ones(1,100)]; % class '-1'
X=[X1,X2];
` So, what I tell you is to split first the data, so in this way the perceptron will learn from the examples...Do this and what will miss is to compare output from perceptron and correct classes

Comment: y_train is a vector with the correct answers (with answers set to -1 for male or 1 for female). With this you think I should be able to run the code as it is now???

Comment: I guess you misunderstood, you must have a train set ( divided in -1 class atribute male, and 1 female class atribute) then you have a test set, ( it does not have the class atribute in this case you do not know if is male or female) so you train perceptron with    `wtag=perceptron(X,Y,w);` (where w means initial weights) `w=[.5 .5 .5]';` X is the part of your training set which are males (-1 class), Y is the part of the training set which are females (1 class), so wtag will be the result of perceptron, and finally you compare wtag with test set.you are done. 
X is the part of the set that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882367/implementing-and-ploting-a-perceptron-in-matlab) I did some time ago.

I uses a matlab code and a function perceptron

```
function [w] = perceptron(X,Y,w_init)

w = w_init;
for iteration = 1 : 100  %<- in practice, use some stopping criterion!
  for ii = 1 : size(X,2)         %cycle through training set
    if sign(w'*X(:,ii)) ~= Y(ii) %wrong decision?
      w = w + X(:,ii) * Y(ii);   %then add (or subtract) this point to w
    end
  end
  sum(sign(w'*X)~=Y)/size(X,2)   %show misclassification rate
end
```

and it is called from code ([@Itamar Katz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/501663/itamar-katz)) like (random data):

```
% input samples
X1=[rand(1,100);rand(1,100);ones(1,100)];   % class '+1'
X2=[rand(1,100);1+rand(1,100);ones(1,100)]; % class '-1'
X=[X1,X2];

% output class [-1,+1];
Y=[-ones(1,100),ones(1,100)];

% init weigth vector
w=[.5 .5 .5]';

% call perceptron
wtag=perceptron(X,Y,w);
% predict
ytag=wtag'*X;


% plot prediction over origianl data
figure;hold on
plot(X1(1,:),X1(2,:),'b.')
plot(X2(1,:),X2(2,:),'r.')

plot(X(1,ytag<0),X(2,ytag<0),'bo')
plot(X(1,ytag>0),X(2,ytag>0),'ro')
legend('class -1','class +1','pred -1','pred +1')
```

I guess this can give you an idea to make the functions you described.
To the error compare the expected result with the real result (class)

Comment: That helps a lot! I still have some more questions though (see above)

Comment: @Itamar Katz, any chance you can help me out here?

Answer (score 1):

Assume your dataset is X, the datapoins, and Y, the labels of the classes.

```
f=newp(X,Y)
```

creates a perceptron.

If you want to create an MLP then:

```
f=newff(X,Y,NN)
```

where NN is the network architecture, i.e. an array that designates the number of neurons at each hidden layer. For example

```
NN=[5 3 2]
```

will correspond to an network with 5 neurons at the first layers, 3 at the second and 2 a the third hidden layer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5445755/creating-a-train-perceptron-in-matlab-for-gender-clasiffication

Comment: above you can see the continuation of this question. I have more details included there!

Answer (score 1):

Well what you call threshold is the Bias in machine learning nomenclature. This should be left as an input for the user because it is used during training.

Also, I wonder why you are not using the builtin matlab functions. i.e newp or newff. e.g.

```
ff=newp(X,Y)
```

Then you can set the properties of the object ff to do your job for selecting gradient descent and so on.

Comment: mainly because this is a school project, and that would not show that I know how to create a perceptron, but also because i do not think it includes everything that I need in order to code for what I need it to do

Comment: the neural network toolbox includes more than you can imagine. Also, what you are asking is for us to code your project. Maybe you should have given attention to the course?

Comment: I have provided the code. I also payed attention to the course. I understand the theory of a perceptron - which is what was taught in the class. The problem is that the HW is in MATLAB (this is not a programming class!) and I never learned MATLAB. I learned JAVA about 8 years ago while studying for my first degree and do not remember much of that either

Comment: Ok, mate no need to get personal but you are not convincing me.