# How to draw classifer line (decision boundary) for perceptron algorithm

Tags: matlab, artificial-intelligence, perceptron

I ran the [perceptron code in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4882367/implementing-and-ploting-a-perceptron-in-matlab) and obtained the below result for a set of data:

Result:

[image]

and obtained this plot

[image]

How can I draw a classification line (Decision boundary) between the two classes???

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71335/decision-boundary-plot-for-a-perceptron

Comment: I want to do it in Matlab